# Inserting data from one table to another using a macro

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access database we're going to use at our swimming pool to scan family passes and log usage.

Currently I have three tables, one for the Family Name and Contact Info (`tblFamilyPass`), another for First Names, Photos, and a unique barcode (`tblPassHolders`), and a third which logs usage (`tblCheckIn`).

I have one query that selects the Surname, Phone# and Address from `tblFamilyPass` that I use to create a relationship between `tblPassHolders` and `tblFamilyPass` and associate individuals with their respective Family Pass, and I'm using a form that uses a macro to scan barcodes and filter through `tblPassHolders` to show the record that corresponds to the barcode.

I have another query that grabs the First name and Family name from `tblPassHolders` that I'm using in `tblCheckIn`, which only has two fields: The First/Last name of the individual, and the time they check in.

Now what I'm trying to do, is modify my macro so that each time I scan a barcode, it adds a new record to `tblCheckIn`.

I'm pretty new to Access, so I'm still doing everything with the macro builder. So far I've only managed to get the table open and select a new record. But my attempts at using `SetValue`:

[image]

Returns the error:

> The object does not contain the automation object 'tblCheckIn'

Inserting the time should be the easy part, my efforts to insert the name of the individual have been even less successful.

How do you insert data into one table while browsing data from another? Will I be able to insert two fields into `tblCheckIn` from a `tblPassHolders` form using macros?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Macro Builder didn't work out, the solution that worked was the following bit of code using the code builder rather than the macro builder:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "CheckIn"
Forms!CheckIn![PASSHOLDER] = Me![BARCODE]
Forms!CheckIn![CHECKINTIME] = Now()
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

There is a point where you have to move past relying on the macro builder.